Add-AppxPackage fails in docker windows image build, error code 0x80073D19 = ERROR_DEPLOYMENT_BLOCKED_BY_USER_LOG_OFF
Is it possible to install .appx app packages into a Windows docker image?
I am trying to build a Windows Docker Image using the "Windows containers" feature of Docker Desktop for Windows 4.33.1.  Whenever I invoke the powershell command Add-AppxPackage from the Dockerfile I get error code 0x80073D19 a.k.a. ERROR_DEPLOYMENT_BLOCKED_BY_USER_LOG_OFF.
The documentation for Add-AppxPackage says that the command will add a signed app package to a user account.  I am guessing that a user is not logged in when building the Docker image, which suggests that .appx packages cannot be installed into Windows Docker images.  Is that right?
I was using the "desktop-windows" builder (i.e. docker buildx use desktop-windows) and trying to build an image via docker build ..
My Dockerfile:
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

RUN powershell -Command Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
RUN powershell -Command mkdir C:\tmp
RUN powershell -Command Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx -OutFile \tmp\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx
RUN powershell -Command Add-AppxPackage \tmp\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx

An excerpt of my console output after executing docker build .:
Step 5/12 : RUN powershell -Command Add-AppxPackage \tmp\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx
 ---> Running in 6220e846522d
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073D19, An error
occurred because a user was logged off.
error 0x8007007E: Failed to load the extension DLL due to the following error:
The specified module could not be found.

